# /dev/dsp not found error while audio playback in centOS 6.x

Tags: c++, centos, simpleaudioengine

I am trying develop an application using C++ which will record audio data from mic and will playback the data. But while trying audio capture I am getting following error message.

```
cannot open /dev/dsp
```

Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know /dev/dsp has been obsoleted. Latest CentOS uses ALSA(Advance Linux Sound Architecture) instead of that. You can check the implementation of [pulse audio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/). I have used the code from the given link to develop an application similar to yours. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

older softwares like dosemu , some (VERY) old ham softwares actually require /dev/dsp be present.There is a package or config that you are missing. Googling for it might help, I forget the exact page that I found the solution on.This applies to fedora and most modern debian based distros as well.